# NiFi convert json to csv using ConvertRecord

Tags: json, csv, apache-nifi

i have a stream of json in apache nifi that contain dynamic fields (maximum 11 fields) and i want to convert it to csv file.

**sample json:**

```
{  
   "field1":"some text",
   "field2":"some text",
   "field3":"some text",
   "field4":"some text",
   "field5":"some text",
   "field6":"some text",
   "field7":"some text"
}
```

i don't wanna using replace or json evaluate; how i do it with ConvertRecord?
using this processor is so odd and hard to work...

**Clear expression about dynamic fields:**
i have 11 fields at total. one record may have contain 7 fields, and next record may contain 11 fields and next 9 fields...

Comment: You are saying dynamic. Will the field names be changing then?

Comment: @sivaprasanna-sethuraman No, i have 11 fields. one record may have contain 7 fields, and next record may contain 11 fields and next 9 fields...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The steps provided below will help you in getting this done.:

- Connect your source processor which generates/outputs the JSON files to `ConvertRecord`.
- Configure `ConvertRecord` and set 'Record Reader' to use `JsonTreeReader` controller service and 'Record Writer' to use `CSVRecordSetWriter` controller service
- Configure both the controller services and set `Schema Registry` property to use `AvroSchemaRegistry`
- Configure `AvroSchemaRegistry`. Go to 'Properties' tab and click the **+** button which lets you add a dynamic property.
- Give some property name (ex: `mySchema`) and for the value, give the Avro schema expected for your input JSON. (You can use `InferAvroSchema` processor to generate Avro schema for your JSON)
- Configure both `JsonTreeReader` and `CsvRecordSetWriter` and set the 'Schema Name' property to the name provided above, in this case, `mySchema`.
- Connect the relationships of `ConvertRecord` to downstream processors according to your need.