# NiFi merge CSV files using MergeRecord

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

i have a stream of JSON records that i convert it into CSV record successfully with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577612/) instruction. but now i want to merge this CSV records into one CSV file. below is that flow:

[image: nifi flow]

at step 5 i face with around 9K csv record, how do i merge it into one csv file using MergeRecord processor?

**my csv header:**

```
field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,field9,field10,field11
```

some of this fields may be null and vary in records.

Comment: Is that a requirement to merge it to exactly one file? That won't be a good approach, IMO. If not, please go through https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.MergeRecord/index.html. `Minimum Number of Records` and `Maximum Number of Records` are the ones that ultimately decide how the merge happens.

Comment: @sivaprasanna-sethuraman not exactly one file, one file that follows from merge strategy (like: bin packing algorithm)

Comment: Please try it out and tell if something doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @sivaprasanna-sethuraman clearly i try this processor; record reader: csvreader and writer: CSVRecordSetWriter; then with default properties  and same schema that i used in json2csv convert i face with this error: "Cannot write Schema Name As Attribute because the Schema Name is not known merge csv"

Comment: Configure `CsvRecordSetWriter` controller service and `Schema Write Strategy` to `Do not write schema`

Comment: thanks it's worked. Do not write schema is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

after this use UpdateAttribute configure it so that it can save the file with a filename and after that use putFile to store it to a specific location

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by using RouteonAttribute processor. Hope this helps someone.

[image: Created a routing till the ${merge.count} reaches 1]

Below is how I configure the processor using ${merge.count:equals(1)}

[image: ${merge.count:equals(1)} ensures all the input flowfiles in the batch are merged into one flowfile and passed downstream]